# svg vs canvas - browser game map?

Tags: svg, canvas, browser

I am trying to make a copy of the popular browser game Travian.com. I am currently working on the maps and I was able to get the farms overview image as a `png`.

What I am trying to accomplish with that map is:

- Each element (farm) should be clickable) and redirect to that specific farm page.
- As you could see on the map, farms are not just simple squares.

Once I had the farms.png picture, I used on online tool to convert a `png` into a .`svg` file. Using a free software, I was able to draw circles around each map to build my `svg`.

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

I recently read about canvas and I was wondering if canvas would be a better option in my case rather using `svg`?

Comment: The answer is it depends. Are you asking just about having clickable areas?  Or are you asking about whether the map itself should be a bitmap image or an SVG?

Comment: Thanks!  I am more asking about whether the map itself should be a bitmap image or an SVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try it yourself and see if it gets redrawn quickly enough that the game is sufficiently responsive for you.  If the map is very detailed, the redraw may be too slow and make your game feel slow.  You really need to try it and see.  If it's too slow for you, then you may need to either:

- use bitmap images, or
- keep the maps as SVGs, but render them to a `Canvas` on first load.  This way they'll be sharp at whatever resolution screen the user has.